# VB.net Foreach doesn't increment

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach, initialization, increment

I have a gridview that will send an email if and only if the checkbox within the gridview is selected.

My gridview looping works fine; however, when I debug line by line in my array loop it is apparent that the `i` never increases from 0.

As you can see, I even tried to increment `i` but it doesn't help either [I know I shouldn't have to increase `i` but I wanted to try something].

Any suggestions?

Global variables:

```
Public arrayLength As Integer

Public email_list As String() = New String(arrayLength) {}
```

Loop:

```
'set array length
For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In DisplaySup.Rows

   If gvrow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

     Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(gvrow.Cells(0).FindControl("SelectUser"), CheckBox)

        If chkRow.Checked Then
                count = count + 1

        End If
  End If
Next

'update public variable
arrayLength = count

For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In DisplaySup.Rows
    Dim CheckBox1 As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvrow.FindControl("SelectUser"), CheckBox)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In DisplaySup.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To email_list.Length - 1

           If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

             Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("SelectUser"), CheckBox)

              If chkRow.Checked Then

                 oneProvided = True

                 Dim v_comp As String = row.Cells(2).Text.ToString()

                 strSearch = "Select email_val from table_name where company = '" & v_comp & "'"

                 Dim SupStr As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSearch, conn)
                 Dim OracleDataAdapterAds As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
                 OracleDataAdapterAds.SelectCommand = SupStr
                 Dim DsAds As DataSet = New DataSet
                 DsAds.Clear()
                 OracleDataAdapterAds.Fill(DsAds, "table_name")

                 email = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
                 email_list(i) = email
                'i = i + 1

             End If

        End If

   Next
Next
```

Comment: the number of elements are determined by the variable `arrayLength` in my example. The number of elements is based on the count value created by how many rows are checked

Comment: I debug and see `count` is correct and `arrayLength` but if I debug `? email_list.Length` I always get 1??

Comment: Well i assume it should be using as boundary since i have line `arrayLength = count` and the global variable is using arrayLength @MattWilko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your global variables and initialise it when your program starts, then you change the `arrayLength` just before your loop. However, this **doesn't** re-initialise your `email_list` - it has already been allocated in memory. If you want to change the size you will have to *re-initialise* it.

It would be better to just define your array without initialising and then only initialise it when you want to use it.

In your global you should have:

```
Public arrayLength As Integer
Public email_list As String()
```

Note: You *can* still initialise it here but there is no point if you are going to re-initialise it before you use it. Given that this is what you are doing, neither of these should be global variables at all, but that is another question and answer.

Then in your code, something like this:

```
arrayLength = count
email_list  = New String(arrayLength) {}
```

Comment: I found another way to do it just now too but yes your way works as well. Thank you for explaining that my initializing should have waited up until I updated the `arrayLength`. As you can see in my answer, `ReDim` can update it even when I initialized it in the global variable

Answer (score 0):

Found the one line of coding I needed.

after    `array_Length = count` I put the line `ReDim email_list(arrayLength)` and it updates the length. Just learned that `ReDim` reallocates space.